# How do I create a list that automatically pulls only unique instances from a second list - even when the second list is changed?

Tags: excel

I know how to do this by hand, but I'd like to automate it since my 2nd list will change. My list is relatively long 5k+ with 2k+ uniques. I have found an array solution on [exceljet](https://exceljet.net/formula/extract-unique-items-from-a-list) but after trying it, it looks like the operation would take hours to execute.

Thank you,

Excel 2016 Windows.

Comment: you can use [PowerQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/power-query-what-is-power-query)

Comment: Could you expand a little bit?

Comment: Post some sample data and I'll help you

Answer (score 0):

You can Create an Excel Advanced Filter ([tutorials](https://www.contextures.com/xladvfilter01.html))

leave the criteria values blank not the header,
and apply unique records
[image]

this is the fastest way to get unique records for long lists